# Android vector drawables vrs png

Tags: android, vector, drawable, assets

Having doubts about this.
I know that vector drawables have the scaling advantage. But before i start making all my new icons in this way, is there any good reason to stick with the good old Pngs?
I would really appreciate a good advice on this.

Answer (score 3):

> But before i start making all my new icons in this way, is there any
>   good reason to stick with the good old Pngs?

if providing only one version of your drawable instead than 3 or 4 scaled versions is not enough a good reason, then you can stick with drawables. Be aware that `VectorDrawable` are supported from lollipop onwards. For the platforms between ICS and Lollipop, the gradle plugin (`1.5.0`) creates a raster  versions, of your vector drawable. You can specify the density you want to export adding

```
 generatedDensities = ['mdpi', 'hdpi', 'xhdpi', 'xxhdpi']
```

to the `defaultConfig` section of your `build.gradle`.

**Edit**

As point out by @Huteri, the `support library v23.2` makes it easier to use it, adding `support-vector-drawable` and `animated-vector-drawable`. Have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E2lNBM38IE&feature=youtu.be&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9e0d55YHgJFHXNZbGHEXJX)

Comment: On android support library 23.2 and Gradle 2.0 we don't need this anymore, http://android-developers.blogspot.co.id/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: I've been using it for weeks, and seems great.